# Programmatically creating and plyaing sound wave forms with flutter

Tags: flutter

How do we go about programmatically create and play sound wave forms (Sinus, triangular, square, saw tooth etc) with flutter ? Is there any audio synthesizer library works with flutter ?

Thanks.

Comment: you got your answer?